# Access Denied on MSSQL restore database script

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I have a SQL Serve instance running on AWS RDS configured to restore a .bak file from AWS S3.
I'm connected through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and run the next script and works well.

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name='db_name', @s3_arn_to_restore_from=‘arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name.bak';
```

But when run the next script `EXEC msdb.dbo.rds_task_status;` I got the error:

> [2022-03-08 12:23:22.060] Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent RESTORE_DB request.
> [2022-03-08 12:23:22.137] Task has been aborted
> [2022-03-08 12:23:22.137] Access Denied

The Options Group has SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE option with a role configured and this role is added to bucket policy.

```
...
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
  "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::code:role/service-role/role_name"
},
"Action": "s3:*",
"Resource": [
  "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
  "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
]
...
```

Any idea how to solve it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look to see what else could be running at the same time : planned tasks (backup?), other users, previous requests that are taking a long time or are blocked? If you can restart the service that might help.

Comment: I'm going to try it again restarting db instance

Comment: Have you set up an IAM role that can access the bucket with the correct permissions, [as documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Enabling)?

Comment: Yes, updated with permissions info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop and restart db instance solved the problem.